# Problem upgrading Samsung S5302 from 2.3.6 to 4.0

Tags: updates, 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-pocket

Device: Samsung S5302

Somebody gave me a link to upgrade my Gingerbread phone - from 2.3.6 to 4.0. I heard that some features won't work in my phone like GPS, dual SIM, and camera.

How do I upgrade this phone?

Comment: I rephrased your question, but I'm not sure it is correct. Is that what you want? Can you give us the link you are talking about?

Answer (score 2):

There no official upgrade of 4.x.x for samsung S5302.
However you can install custom ROMs like Cyanogenmods to upgrade your phone. but you need to ROOT your phone before installing custom ROM.

Check this out [Custom Rom For Galaxy Y Duos Lite GT S5302](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2324720)

also this :  [CyanogenMOD 9.0 [ICS 4.0.4] for Galaxy Pocket](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=40141782)